# I cannot access the data when extracting data from firebase in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My code is written like this, but I cannot access the data in the output I get?

```
 void getMessages() async {
    final messages = await _firestore.collection('mesajlar').get();
    for (var message in messages.docs) {
      print(message.data);
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: You have to get document `data` from message.. like print(messgae.data)..

Comment: actually i did that but i deleted it but i can't see the data when i do that

Comment: "actually i did that" Please edit your question to show what you did.

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling `data` as a property when it is actually a function, you can see that in the [documentation for `DocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html), which `QueryDocumentSnapshot` implements. So all you have to change is the print:

```
print(message.data());
```